# Issue suddenly to execute console.log()

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>01 exo synthese - Devinette</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="riddle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
(() => {
    const LIMITS = { MIN: 0, MAX: 100 };
    
    // Messages pour l'utilisateur
    const INVALID_INPUT_ERROR = "Entrée invalide. Veuillez réessayer.";
    const LOWER_GUESS = "Nombre essayé {input}, plus bas";
    const HIGHER_GUESS = "Nombre essayé {input}, plus haut";
    const GUESS_PROMPT = `Deviner le nombre entre ${LIMITS.MIN} et ${LIMITS.MAX}`;
    const SUCCESS = "Parfait le nombre était bien {numberToFind}! Tu as trouvé en {tryToFind} fois";
    
    // Expression de validation
    const VALID_NUMBER_REGEX = /^[0-9]+$/;

    /**
     * Vérifie si la valeur donnée est un nombre valide ou non.
     * @param {number} number - La valeur à vérifier.
     * @returns {boolean} - Retourne 'true' si la valeur est un nombre valide, sinon 'false'.
     */
    const isValidNumber = number => VALID_NUMBER_REGEX.test(number);


    /**
     * Renvoie un nombre aléatoire entre les bornes min et max incluses.
     * @param {number} min - La borne inférieure, incluse
     * @param {number} max - La borne supérieure, incluse
     * @returns {number} - Un nombre aléatoire entre min et max, inclus
     */
    const getRandomNumberBetween = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)-min);

    /**
     * Vérifie si le nombre entré par l'utilisateur est égal au nombre à deviner
     * @param {number} numberToFind - Le nombre à deviner
     * @param {number} tryToFind - Le nombre d'essais effectués par l'utilisateur (par défaut 1)
     * @returns {void} - Rien n'est renvoyé, mais la fonction affiche un message dans la console en fonction du résultat
     */
    const checkNumber = (numberToFind, tryToFind = 1) => {
            const input = prompt(GUESS_PROMPT);
            if (!isValidNumber(input) || input < LIMITS.MIN || input > LIMITS.MAX) {
                alert(INVALID_INPUT_ERROR);
                return checkNumber(numberToFind, tryToFind);
            }
            if (input != numberToFind) {
                const message = input > numberToFind ? LOWER_GUESS.replace("{input}", input) : HIGHER_GUESS.replace("{input}", input);
                console.log(message);
                return checkNumber(numberToFind, tryToFind + 1);
            }
            return console.log(SUCCESS.replace("{numberToFind}", numberToFind).replace("{tryToFind}", tryToFind));
    };
    

    const numberToFind = getRandomNumberBetween(LIMITS.MIN, LIMITS.MAX);

    checkNumber(numberToFind)
})();
```

Hello,
My issue is to have a code that worked, I just changed this block of code to make it more optimized in my checkNumber function

```
if (input != numberToFind) {
    return input > numberToFind
        ? (console.log(LOWER_GUESS.replace("{input}", input)), checkNumber(numberToFind, tryToFind + 1))
        : (console.log(HIGHER_GUESS.replace("{input}", input)), checkNumber(numberToFind, tryToFind + 1));
}
```

to

```
if (input != numberToFind) {
    const message = input > numberToFind ? LOWER_GUESS.replace("{input}", input) : HIGHER_GUESS.replace("{input}", input);
    console.log(message);
    return checkNumber(numberToFind, tryToFind + 1);
}
```

When I test the new code, by injecting directly into a browser console, the code works very, well. But by testing the html page that does nothing but launch the scripts that were already working long before which I no longer touch from the start. the code no longer displays anything in the console logs.
So, that the console is supposed to display a lower or higher by indicating what has just been entered by the user.
So, suddenly I came back to the old code and there same problem while everything worked well but works by injecting the code directly into the console.

By testing, nevertheless with a settimeout I was able to overcome the problem, but my question is suddenly, why? Why I suddenly need a settimeout when it worked well ? at least to be able to understand.

If anyone has the answer, thank you in advance

Comment: "But by testing the html page" - can you share that, such that others can reproduce the problem?

Comment: If your problem is that some code is not running any more, can you get rid of the irritating alerts and present a minimal reproducible example? Ideally show your code before that was working, and after that is not working.

Comment: Yes @NicoHaase, this is the html code to call the script 
```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>01 exo synthese - Devinette</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="riddle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i solved my issue, it was just prompt() blocked the dom to load even if my script was loaded after